# collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute thread safe c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I received an error when creating one thread to add to listbox from one list
here is code

```
private void textBoxSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBoxSuggest.Items.Clear();
       {
           string temp = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
           mythread = new Thread(()=> UpdateListBox(temp) );
           mythread.Start();
       }

    }

    private void UpdateListBox(string queyt)
    {
        if (queyt !=null)
        {
            if (myPrefixTree.Find(queyt))
            {
                var match = myPrefixTree.GetMatches(queyt);
                    foreach (string item in match)
                        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => listBoxSuggest.Items.Add(item)));
            }
        }

    }
```

I received an error

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

I need a solution to problem...

update...
While running the program, I received an error in

```
  foreach (string item in match)
```

Comment: what line of code does that error come from?  something else is going on here

Comment: You are probably looping through a list and in that loop; you are deleting/adding items from/to that list. This doesn't appear to happen in this piece of code. Where does the error appear?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you called something, such as .Add or .Remove, which edits the content of your enumeration while it was being iterated over. this causes the iteration to fail, because now it's not sure whether to proceed with the new element (which may have an index set before the current index) or skip the old element (which may have already been processed or may even be the current item).

You need to make sure that any loop which may modify contents of the loop it's calling over instead iterates over a copy of that enumeration. [ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb298736(v=vs.100).aspx) and [ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261(v=vs.100).aspx) can both server this purpose -

```
foreach(var item in collection.ToArray()) ...
```

- or -

```
foreach(var item in collection.ToList()) ...
```

This means that when something inevitably calls `collection.Add` somewhere within the body of your loop, it modifies the original collection, not the one being iterated, and thus preventing errors. It can, however, mean that it will process over something that was removed earlier in the iteration, in which case you may need a more complicated soltion.